# How to remove shortcuts from the preferences menu using terminal

Tags: command-line, unity

I want to remove the following shortcuts from the preferences menu from terminal: **Main Menu**, **Remote Desktop** & **Appearance**. Can anyone help?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### For every user

If you want to edit it for everyone, then you can move desired `.desktop` files from `/usr/share/applications` directory, in your case `alacarte.desktop`, `vino.desktop` and `gnome-appearance-properties.desktop`

for example

```
cd /usr/share/applications
sudo mv alacarte.desktop gnome-appearance-properties.desktop vinagre.desktop /somedir
```

#### For one user

If you want to edit it for one user, you will probably need to edit file `~/.config/menus/settings` - an xml file. So, adding `<exclude><filename>desired_file.desktop</filename></exclude>` in the second `<menu>... </menu>` part could do this. You can see what you will need to add there if you look what changes happen when you disable something in alacarte (GUI for editing menus).

Comment: It is not working. Still the shortcuts are there in the preferences menu.

Comment: which one youre trying ? because I tried part with moving .desktop files from /usr/share/applications and it worked. Didnt edited xml file, just noticed changes made by alacarte

Comment: ok, if i will have in .config/menus/settings written to include it will stay there even when moved from /usr/share/applications

Comment: probably found out reason... check if user dont have files in .local/share/applications

Answer (score 0):

Here a GUI way to do it. Open [Alacarte](http://packages.ubuntu.com/alacarte) [image: Install Alacarte]. (I think it's installed by default on Ubuntu).

It's very intuitive and easy to use. You can enable/disable any element.

[image]

Comment: Thanks, but i know the GUI method :)