# how to disable window close using key combination <Alt>F4?

Tags: keyboard, shortcut-keys, chroot, gsettings, kiosk

I am new here.
Recently I tried to create custom distribution which has a single application running all the time. (kiosk mode)
I would like to prevent unauthorized window closing from users.
I tried:

```
gsettings set org.gnome.desktop.wm.keybindings close "['<Alt>w']"
```

on Chroot environment and my iso is Ubuntu 16.04 LTS

which throws following error:

```
(process:24985): dconf-WARNING **: failed to commit changes to dconf: Error spawning command line 'dbus-launch --autolaunch=80a6da0249c733006b0ed2ea57aaee4f --binary-syntax --close-stderr': Child process exited with code 1
```

Are there any other ways to set default key bindings on Ubuntu unity?

I will only create a user on OS installation.

Comment: Have you considered launching the application inside a `while true` loop.  This will allow closing the application if it hangs.  Otherwise, find the shortcut in the configuration and remove it.

Comment: @ BillThor  hi bill, i haven't tried that. can you share me an example? i don't understand why i need an endless loop!

Comment: Two reasons:  If the application crashes, you want it to restart; and if a user manages to close the application, you want it to restart.  If Alt-F4 is enabled, it may be useful if the application hangs.

Comment: yes, that makes sense. i tried that method with firefox as kiosk application. but it put me into a state where i can't debug the state. infinite loop is hard to handle.

Comment: i found that warning is a kind of ubuntu unity bug. Its associated with close shortcut.

Answer (score 1):

Haha, I have this disabled!

1. Search "shortcuts" in the thing that looks like my picture. It may be a different color.
2. Open shortcuts and switch to the tab "shortcuts". Go to the "Window" shortcuts.
3. Click on ALT+F4, and hit backspace to disable.

Comment: My dear friend @BJC_17493 are you suggesting me to try using keyboard settings. in Chroot mode i can't open unity GUI.

Comment: Oh... of course I'm wrong. I don't know how to do it from command line... I'll try looking it up.

Comment: OK. I found a question that should help you.  http://askubuntu.com/questions/39565/how-to-remove-shortcuts-from-preferences-menu-from-terminal

Comment: no. thats not what i am looking for. i want to disable keyboard shortcuts.  :-(

Comment: Ah ha! I found one. I really really think this will help:  http://askubuntu.com/questions/461701/disable-all-unity-keyboard-shortcuts-using-the-command-line